# Three20 and TTTableImageItem

Tags: objective-c, three20

I m starting a new project and looking into three20 for the table views.
I saw that TTTableImageItem offers part of the required functionality for free,to lazily load the images,but what i want to do is also  save each photo to  disk after the first load  so the next time i will fetch them from  there.
In previous cases i was doing manualy the loading of the visible images at my model ,so i could also save them .
Is there any way to achieve such a thing and keep the rest of the functionallity TTTableImageItem offers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes TTCache will do this for you.

```
[[TTURLCache sharedCache] storeImage:image forURL:URL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your suggestion seems to be what im looking for,though one thing that i havent sorted out is how to get notified that the image has loaded so to store it on disk.
I see the TTTableImageItemCell has a TTImageView which has a delegate property for the TTImageViewDelegate protocol,but im not sure how i could use that..But i will propably need to subclass TTTableItem and TTTableItemCell to have custom UI ,so i could just manipulate directly the TTImageView and use the delegate ,is that correct?